# Expected value with balls and bins

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Ten distinguishable balls are thrown into 100 distinguishable bins independently and uniformly at random. Let X be the number of bins with at least two balls.

1. Compute E(X) and use Markov’s inequality to estimate an upper bound on P [X ≥ 2]
2. Compute Var(X) and use Chebyshev’s inequality to estimate an upper bound on P [X ≥ 2]

I'm having trouble with establishing the expected number of bins with at least 2 balls.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Let X be a random variable such that X_i = 1 if bin i has ≥ 2 balls and 0 otherwise. Then we can calculate that for a given bin, P(≥ 2 balls) = 1 - P(1 ball) - P(0 balls).
- The probability that the first ball falls into a given bin is clearly 1/100, so P(1 ball) = $(1/100)^{10}$ since we have 10 balls.
- P(0 balls) = $(99/100)^{10}$ since on each toss 99 of the bins don't get the ball. Then we have $1 - (1/100)^{10} - (99/100)^{10} = 0.095$.

This is where my understanding is failing. I believe the above means that for a given bin i, the probability that it contains 2 or more balls is 0.095. By linearity of expectations, we should do $0.095*100$ to get the probability that *any* bin of the 100 has 2 or more balls. Clearly though this is nonsensical as it gives a probability over 1. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Why would you expect the expectation to be less than $1$?

Comment: @lulu because we're throwing 10 balls into 100 bins, so on average each bin will get 0.1 balls

Comment: Yes, it is.  I already deleted that comment.  Why would you think that the expected value should be $<1$?  $E[X]$ is not the probability of anything.

Comment: Sorry responded before the edit! My confusion is that 9 bins with 2 balls each does not make sense if we have 10 balls to spread across 100 bins

Comment: No worries.  Also, I don't understand your computation of $P(1)$.  There are $10$ balls and $100$ bins so $P(1)=10\times \left(\frac 1{100}\right)^1\times \left(\frac {99}{100}\right)^9$

Comment: Ah, got it.  As I said, the problem is in your computation of $P(1)$.

Comment: Got it, thank you! So with that I calculate P(2) = 1 - .0913 - .904 = 0.0047. Then we can do P(2) * 100 since we have 100 bins to get E(2) = 0.47 which makes a lot more sense. If you wouldn't mind sharing, what thought process did you use to get that equation for P(1)?

Comment: I get $.004266$ for $P(≥2)$.  And $0.904382075$ for $P(0)$.

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't using the correct # of sig figs, .0042 is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @lulu for his help here.

I was calculating P(1) incorrectly. $(1)=10×(1/100)^1×(99/100)^9  = 0.09135172474$. With that I calculate P(2) = =1 - 0.09135172474 - 0.904382075 = 0.0042. Then we can do P(2) * 100 since we have 100 bins to get E(2) = 0.47 which makes sense.